# Meaning of the sentence "A gentleman is someone who does not what he wants to do but what he should do'

Tags: sentence-meaning

May I know the meaning of the sentence "A gentleman is someone who does not what he wants to do but what he should do"

Comment: "A gentleman is someone who does not *do* what he wants to do, but *instead does* what he should do"

Comment: What particular part of the sentence is unclear? There are too many components to address for there to be a focused answer unless you can narrow it down. As I see it, there are several main components: (1) *a gentleman is someone who*, (2) *[he] does not what he wants to do*, and (3) *[he does] what he should do*. Does your confusion exist in only one of those three areas?

Answer (score 2):

The sentence means, roughly, that there are obligations incumbent on someone who aspires to the status of *gentleman* (or higher). Cf. [noblesse oblige](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noblesse_oblige).

> Noblesse oblige (/noʊˌblɛs əˈbliːʒ/; French: [nɔblɛs ɔbliʒ]) is a French expression used in English. It translates as "nobility obliges" and denotes the concept that nobility extends beyond mere entitlements and requires the person who holds such a status to fulfill social responsibilities. For example, a primary obligation of a nobleman could include generosity towards those around him.